Initializing database using mysql-operator
I have a rather complex application, with several applicative components and a MySQL database. I am using kubernetes and Helm manage it. I would like to clusterize the database using mysql-operator, but I am uncertain about the standard, cleanest way to initialize the db users and tables.
I have found this answer using a custom pod, but it looks like it needs manually managing dependencies from the application components to the db init pod, which doesn't sound right.
I'd prefer a solution integrated with mysql-operator, like /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d in standard dockerized MySQL.
